# How to add Magento admin router correctly to avoid conflicts between extensions

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to overwrite Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product to add functionality to  add some actions to the grid of the "Manage Products" page. I wonder how to get the routers and redirects right to prevent conflicts with other extensions (such as Enhanced Admin Product Grid).

I came up with two options, both work, but I'm not sure about the implications.

**Option 1**

Use the standard adminhtml/catalog_product router and simply add my module. This will `POST` the new grid action to `www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/example`.

Extract from `config.xml`:

```
<config>
   ...
   <admin>
      <routers>
         <adminhtml>
            <args>
               <modules>
                  <mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyCompany_MyModule</mymodule>
               </modules>
            </args>
         </adminhtml>
      </routers>
   </admin>
</config>
```

Observer to add action to the grid:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer {

   public function addExampleAction($observer) {
      $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
      if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
         && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'catalog_product') {
         $block->addItem('example', array(
             'label' => 'execute exampleAction',
             'url' => $block->getUrl('adminhtml/*/example')
         ));
      }
   }
```

Note that `adminhtml` is specified as the first part in the `$block->getUrl()` statement. With `*/*/example`, the module won't work with 'Enhanced Admin Product Grid' because it would `POST` to `www.mysite.com/index.php/enhancedgrid/catalog_product/example` - which doesn't exist. (I suppose this problem occurs with all modules that ... rewrite routes?)

**Option 2**

Add a new route to my module. This will `POST` the new grid action to `www.mysite.com/index.php/myrouter/catalog_product/example`.

Extract from `config.xml`:

```
<config>
   ...
   <admin>
      <routers>
         <myroute>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>MyCompany_MyModule</module>
               <frontName>myroute</frontName>
            </args>
         </myroute>
      </routers>
   </admin>
</config>
```

Observer to add action to the grid:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer {

   public function addExampleAction($observer) {
      $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
      if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
         && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'catalog_product') {
         $block->addItem('example', array(
             'label' => 'execute exampleAction',
             'url' => $block->getUrl('myroute/*/example')
         ));
      }
   }
```

Note the difference in the `$block->getUrl()` statement.

**Questions**

1. Which options ensures better compatibility with other extensions? Or is there a better way?
2. Where would I redirect to in the Controller Class once the action has been processed? This is my simplyfied controller:

   ```
   class MyCompany_MyModule_Catalog_ProductController 
         extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController {

       public function exampleAction() {
          ... do stuff ...
          $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
       }
   }
   ```

   Let's assume Enhanced Admin Product Grid is installed, too. With option 1, `*/*/index` redirects to `www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index`. Although this works fine, my feeling is that the correct url should be `www.mysite.com/index.php/enhancedgrid/catalog_product/index`. But I have no clue if it really does matter and how to do it if I don't know which other extensions are installed.

   With option 2, `*/*/index` redirects to `www.mysite.com/index.php/myrouter/catalog_product/index` which results in an empty page because MyCompany_MyModule_Catalog_ProductController doesn't have indexAction(). So I'd have to use `adminhtml/*/index` instead which redirects to `www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index` - same doubts as above...

**Thank you to anyone who takes the time to read this lenghty question!!!**

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and tried to answer the questions myself, at least for number 1 I'm now quite confident:

1. Option 1 (using the standard admin frontname (adminhtml router) rather than defining a custom one) is the preferred way, as explained by Alan Storm [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_admin_cms_default_routers):

   *"although it’s possible to define multiple front names for the admin router, I’d advise against doing so (despite [previous advice](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers)). There are parts of the admin console application that assume a front name of admin. While pages will load and work with alternate admin frontnames, certain features (such as the media gallery integration for the rich text editor), may not.*

   *While it’s possible to work around these special cases, you’re better off [slipping your module](http://web-magician.blogspot.com/2009/04/secret-feature-of-magento-13-sharing.html) into the admin front name/adminhtml config router node, and then being careful there’s no overlap between your controller names and the Mage_Adminhtml module controller names."*
2. I still haven't thouroughly understood, why `*/*/index` works, which redirects to www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index regardless of rewrites defined in other modules. But it works, so I'll leave it for that.